# Finding blank cells and moving row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find people who are missing their street address and moving their row to a separate tab in my sheet.

```vb
Sub NEW_NoAddress()

    Const Title As String = "Move Data Rows"
    Const scCol As Long = 6
    Const dCol As Long = 1
    Const Criteria As String = "ISEmpty()"
           
    ' Remove any previous filters.
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

    ' Filter.
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range (Headers and Data)
    Set srg = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    srg.AutoFilter scCol, Criteria

    ' Count the number of matches.
    Dim sdrg As Range ' Source Data Range (Without Headers)
    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim sdccrg As Range ' Source Data Criteria Column Range
    Set sdccrg = sdrg.Columns(scCol)
    Dim drCount As Long ' Destination Rows Count (Matches Count)
    drCount = Application.Subtotal(103, sdccrg)

    ' Move if there are matches.
    
    If drCount > 0 Then ' matches found
        
        Dim sdfrrg As Range ' Source Data Filtered Rows Range
        Set sdfrrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell
        Set dCell = Sheet10.Cells(Sheet10.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
        With sdfrrg

            .Copy dCell
            
            ' Either delete the entire worksheet rows...
            '.EntireColumn.Delete
            
            ' ... or remove filter to prevent...
            Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
            ' ... deleting the entire worksheet rows leaving possible data
            ' to the right (after the empty column) intact.
            .Delete xlShiftUp
        
        End With

    Else ' no matches
        
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
   
    End If
        
End Sub
```

I tried "<>", "<> **", " "" ", I think I tried one that had vbStringISNull, (), and other things I came across in Google. I considered going the other direction and keeping the <> to move those who have an address, but I'd rather move the incorrect entries to my exceptions tab.

Answer (score 0):

### Move Matching Rows

- I'm glad you like my code. Unfortunately, it has a big mistake:

  ```
   drCount = Application.Subtotal(103, sdccrg)
  ```

  which is similar to Excel's `ACOUNT` which results in 0 when selecting blanks.
- I've seen this in a couple of codes and adopted it as valid. Was I in for a surprise.
- When you plan on using such a code so intensely, you want to move the changing variables to the arguments section to easily use it many times (see the long procedure below).
- You can use the new procedure...

  - ... for your first question like this:

    ```
    Sub MoveMatchRows()
        MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 4, "FD.Matching Gifts FY22", Sheet2, 1, False
    End Sub
    ```
  - ... for yesterday's question like this:

    ```
    Sub NEW_Move_Stock_InKind_DAF()
        MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 44, "<>*/*", Sheet8, 1, False
    End Sub
    ```
  - ... and for today's question like this:

    ```
    Sub NewNoAddress()
        MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 6, "=", Sheet10, 1, False
    End Sub
    ```
- I have declared `SourceCriteria` as variant and added `xlFilterValues` to be able to use multiple criteria, e.g. `Array("1", "2")`.

**The Procedure**

```vb
Sub MoveMatchingRows( _
        ByVal SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SourceColumn As Long, _
        ByVal SourceCriteria As Variant, _
        ByVal DestinationWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        Optional ByVal DestinationColumn As Long = 1, _
        Optional ByVal DoClearPreviousDestinationData As Boolean = False)
    
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Move Matching Rows"
    
    ' Remove any previous filters.
    If SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Filter.
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range (Headers and Data)
    Set srg = SourceWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    srg.AutoFilter SourceColumn, SourceCriteria, xlFilterValues
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Data Range (no headers).
    Dim sdrg As Range
    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Clear Destination worksheet.
    If DoClearPreviousDestinationData Then ' new data, copies headers
        DestinationWorksheet.Cells.Clear
    End If
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the Source Data Filtered Rows Range.
    Dim sdfrrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sdfrrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not sdfrrg Is Nothing Then
        
        ' Create a reference to the Destination Cell (also, add headers).
        Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell
        Set dCell = DestinationWorksheet.Cells(1, DestinationColumn)
        If IsEmpty(dCell) Then
            srg.Rows(1).Copy dCell
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set dCell = DestinationWorksheet.Cells( _
                DestinationWorksheet.Rows.Count, DestinationColumn) _
                .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
        With sdfrrg
            .Copy dCell
            
            ' Either delete the entire worksheet rows...
            '.EntireColumn.Delete
            
            ' ... or remove filter to prevent...
            SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
            ' ... deleting the entire worksheet rows leaving possible data
            ' to the right (after the empty column) intact.
            .Delete xlShiftUp
        
        End With
    
    Else ' no matches
        
        SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
   
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Mistake or no, I _really_ have liked your code. I can't tell you how far that has gotten me with everything. It took me a minute to figure out how to use the new procedure you provided, but I think I'm getting it now. This should really help condense things, as I have 16 modules right now. It's getting fairly ridiculous. Thank you!!!